# Disable button when there is no internet connection

Tags: android

My code looks like this:

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);

    b_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         if (started) {
             started = false;
             mediaPlayer.pause();
             b_play.setText(R.string.start);
         } else {
             started = true;
             mediaPlayer.start();
             b_play.setText(R.string.pause);

         }
     }
});
```

How can I disable b_play button when there is no internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to continuously check whether there is an internet connection or not and disable/enable the button based on that. Go with the solution below:

First create Receiver class (let's name it NetworkStateReceiver) that extends BroadcastReceiver. NetworkStateReceiver invokes different methods of the interface based on the availabily of the internet:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public interface NetworkListener {
    void onNetworkAvailable();
    void onNetworkUnavailable();
}

private NetworkListener networkListener;

public NetworkStateReceiver(NetworkListener networkListener) {
    this.networkListener = networkListener;
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
        NetworkInfo ni = (NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
         Log.i("app", "Network " + ni.getTypeName() + " connected");
            networkListener.onNetworkAvailable();
        }
    }
    if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
       Log.d("app", "There's no network connectivity");
        networkListener.onNetworkUnavailable();
    }
  }
}
```

And then create instance of that NetworkStateReceiver class implementing NetworkStateReceiver.NetworkListener interface:

```
NetworkStateReceiver networkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver(new NetworkStateReceiver.NetworkListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNetworkAvailable() {
            b_play.setEnabled(true); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkUnavailable() {
            b_play.setEnabled(false); 
        }
    });
```

After creating the instance of the NetworkStateReceiver, register it like this:

```
registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

And don't forget to unregister it inside onDestroy() method:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if there is some internet connection:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

After, you have to disable (or enable) the button

```
myButton.setEnabled(isNetworkAvailable());
```

**EDIT:**
You'll need this at the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public final boolean isInternetOn()
{
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
    if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED )
    {
        // MESSAGE TO SCREEN FOR TESTING (IF REQ)
        //Toast.makeText(this, connectionType + ” connected”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
            ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  )
    {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
//-----------------------
if(isInternetOn()){
   btn.setEnabled(true);
}
else{
   btn.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Last line : btn.setEnabled(isInternetOn());

Comment: there's an `if statement` so it goes like this: if there's Internet -> btn enabled, else (there's no Internet) btn disabled

Comment: Both are same. If isInternetOn() returns true button will be set to true else false. Code is simplified by my line.

Comment: true, sorry, indeed both are same